# Unable to get attribute value

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I have the following data in the column XMLData of type xml in a table -

```
<ns0:SR xmlns:ns0="http://Country.Regions" 
    xmlns:Country="http://Country.Regions/Types">
  <Sale Category="Heavy Load" Quantity="1" Value="110" />
</ns0:SR>
```

I am trying to get the value of Quantity from below query but getting an error -

```
select
    XmlData.value('(/SR/Sale[@Category="HeavyLoad"]/@Quantity)[1]', 'int')      
from Cars
```

There is no element named `Category`. I tried removing `/SR/` still getting the same error. I am new to XQuery. Would appreciate answer containing using only `.value`. We are using SQL Server 2008

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to **respect** and use the XML namespace defined in your XML data. And secondly, you have a typo in your XPath (it should be `[@Category="Heavy Load"]` - with a **space** between `Heavy` and `Load`)

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://Country.Regions' AS ns0)
SELECT
    XmlData.value('(/ns0:SR/Sale[@Category="Heavy Load"]/@Quantity)[1]', 'int') 
FROM Cars
```

Comment: Thanks marc. Worked like a charm. Will take care of the typo, :)